# How to count checked checkboxes in different divs

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

```
<head><title>STUDENT WISE EXAM BACKLOGS DISPLAY FOR EXAM REGISTRATION</title>

<style type="text/css">
    th {
        font-family:Arial;
        color:black;
        border:1px solid #000;
    }
    thead {
        display:table-header-group;
    }
    tbody {
        display:table-row-group;
    }
    td  {
       border:1px solid #000;   
    }
    </style> 
<script type="text/javascript" >
function check_value(year,sem){

ysem="ys"+year+sem;
var reg=document.registration.regulation.value;
subjectsys="subjects"+year+sem;
amountsys="amount"+year+sem;

if(year==1){
if(sem==1){
var value_list = document.getElementById("ys11").getElementsByTagName('input');
}   
if(sem==2){
var value_list = document.getElementById("ys12").getElementsByTagName('input');
}
  }elseif(year==2){
if(sem==1){
var value_list = document.getElementById("ys21").getElementsByTagName('input');
}   
if(sem==2){
var value_list = document.getElementById("ys22").getElementsByTagName('input');
}
  }elseif(year==3){
if(sem==1){
var value_list = document.getElementById("ys31").getElementsByTagName('input');
}   
if(sem==2){
var value_list = document.getElementById("ys32").getElementsByTagName('input');
}
  }elseif(year==4){
if(sem==1){
var value_list = document.getElementById("ys41").getElementsByTagName('input');
}   
if(sem==2){
var value_list = document.getElementById("ys42").getElementsByTagName('input');
}
  }

  values = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<value_list.length; i++){
if  (value_list[i].checked) {
    values=values+1;
}
  }
  document.getElementById(subjectsys).value=values;
  if (values=="0")
    {
    document.getElementById(amountsys).innerHTML="";
    return;
    }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
      document.getElementById(amountsys).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","fee.php?year="+year+"&reg="+reg+"&sem="+sem+"&sub="+values,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  } 
  </script>
     </head>

<form id="registration" name="registration" action=subverify.php method=POST></br></br>    <center> Backlog Subjects for <b>My HtNo</b>
</br></br>
<table border='1'><tr>
<th width='40'>&nbsp;</th><th width='90'>Regulation</th><th width='40'>Year</th>
<th width='40'>Sem</th><th width='350'>Subname</th>
<th width='70'>Internals</th><th width='70'>Externals</th>
</tr><div id="ys41"><tr>
<td width='40'><center><input type="checkbox" name="sub[]" value="344" 
onclick="check_value(4,1)"></center></td>
<td width='90'><center>R07</center></td><td width='40'><center>4</center></td><td     width='40'><center>1</center></td>
<td width='350'>EMBEDDED SYSTEMS</td><td width='70'><center>18</center></td>
<td width='70'><center>17</center></td></tr><tr><td colspan=5 align=right><b>Subjects:     </b><input size=2 type=textbox id=subjects41 name=subjects41 value=0     maxlength=2 readonly=readonly></td>
<td align=right><b>Amount  :</b></td>
<input type='hidden' name='regulation' id=regulationsubjects41 value='R07'>
<td><div id="amount41"><input type="textbox" name="amountval41" value="0" size="5"     maxlength="5" readonly="readonly"></div></td></tr></div><div id="ys42"><tr>
<td width='40'><center><input type="checkbox" name="sub[]" value="527" 
onclick="check_value(4,2)"></center></td>
<td width='90'><center>R07</center></td><td width='40'><center>4</center></td><td     width='40'><center>2</center></td>
<td width='350'>DESIGN PATTERNS</td><td width='70'><center>12</center></td>
<td width='70'><center>14</center></td></tr><tr><td colspan=5 align=right><b>Subjects:     </b><input size=2 type=textbox id=subjects42 name=subjects42 value=0     maxlength=2 readonly=readonly></td>
<td align=right><b>Amount  :</b></td>
<input type='hidden' name='regulation' id=regulationsubjects42 value='R07'>
<td><div id="amount42"><input type="textbox" name="amountval42" value="0" size="5"     maxlength="5" readonly="readonly"></div></td></tr></div><tr><td colspan=7><center><b><div     id="maintotal"><input type="textbox" name="maintotal" value="0" size="5"     maxlength="5" readonly="readonly"></div></center></b></td></tr><tr></tr></table></br></br>    <center><input type='hidden' name='htno' value='08KN1A1219'>
<input type='submit' value='Register'></center></form></br>
```

This is a output of a PHP file with using dynamic data in the form.
I want to count only the `checkboxes` in the `<div>` tag and it has to display in that subjects `<div>` tag like `subjects41` and `subjects42`. Can anyone please help me to update this JavaScript? It passes some ajax request for displaying the fee.

Comment: all the answers given here are Jquery..BTW, why shouldnt you count in the php itself?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length
```

Comment: is this jquery ?? but i need the count of checked checkboxes in my div

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple jquery something like this

```
var count=0;
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
if(this.is(":checked")){
count+=1;
}
})

alert(count);
```

Comment: i dont want jquery for this but i need to count checked checkboxes in different divs

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery ,

```
var ids = $('input[name="nameofcheckbox[]"]:checked')
                    .map(function(){
                                  return this.value;
                   }).get();
```

Comment: i dont want jquery for this but i need to count checked checkboxes in different divs

Answer (score 0):

Without Jquery:

```
var div = document.getElementById("ys41");
var checkboxes = [];

function getCheckBoxes(el) {
    //check this is an element
    if (el.nodeType == 1) {
        var i = 0;

        //get the children
        var elements = el.childNodes;

        // Loop through children
        while (typeof elements[i] !== 'undefined') {

            //check this is an element
            if (elements[i].nodeType == 1) {
                // If the type is checkbox add it to the array
                if (elements[i].getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox') {
                    checkboxes[checkboxes.length] = elements[i];
                }
                // Otherwise recurse
                else {
                    if (elements[i].childNodes.length > 0) {
                        getCheckBoxes(elements[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}

getCheckBoxes(div);
```

Caveat: I don't have time right now to check that this works ;). If it doesn't comment and I'll correct this evening.

Comment: The function works. The problem is that you're trying to select the checkboxes of divs with ids like 'ys11'. Those divs don't contain any elements however. Running my function on the form (as I'm doing in the js fiddle you posted) finds the checkboxes. You need to work out how to get the correct rows for the correct years.

Comment: i tried it but it is not working i mean it is counting all the checked checkboxes in the page

Answer (score 0):

Since you wanted to do this using javascript,

```
<FORM>
<INPUT TYPE=checkbox NAME="chkboxarray" VALUE="1"><br>
<INPUT TYPE=checkbox NAME="chkboxarray" VALUE="2"><br>
<INPUT TYPE=checkbox NAME="chkboxarray" VALUE="3"><br>
<INPUT TYPE=button NAME="CheckAll" VALUE="checkbox count" onClick="modify_boxes()">
</FORM>​

function modify_boxes(){
    var total_boxes = document.forms[0].chkboxarray.length;
    var count =0;
    for ( i=0 ; i < total_boxes ; i++ ){
     if (document.forms[0].chkboxarray[i].checked ==true)
     count++;        
    }   
 alert(count);        
}​​​​
```

Working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PRnLX/)

Comment: i need to count checked checkboxes in different divs nothing is there here for the div

Answer (score -1):

here you go, this's what you asked :)

```
var i=0;
var checks= 0;
divelem = document.getElementById("divelem");
  while(i < divelem.childNodes.length){
  if( divelem.childNodes[i].nodeType != 3         //not empty space
      && divelem.childNodes[i].getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox' //is checkbox? 
      && divelem.childNodes[i].checked ){                         // is checked?
            checks++;
     }
      i++;  
 }
alert("no of checkboxes checked in div are: "+checks);
```

I prefer you count in the php itself.

**UPDATE:**
here's the complete code, I am damn sure it's working. It gives all checkboxes that are checked in all div elements. Pls check.

```
<html>
<div >
1.<input type="checkbox" value="check1" / ></br>
2.<input type="checkbox" value="check2" / ></br>
3.<input type="checkbox" value="check3" / ></br>
</div>
<div >
4.<input type="checkbox" value="check4" / ></br>
5.<input type="checkbox" value="check5" / ></br>
</div>
<input type="button" value="count check" onclick="check()"> 
<script>
function check(){ //function can count checkboxes for all div elements in document

var checks= 0;
var divelems = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(no=0;no<divelems.length;no++){
  var i=0;
    while(i < divelems[no].childNodes.length){
    if( divelems[no].childNodes[i].nodeType != 3         //not empty space
    && divelems[no].childNodes[i].getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox' //is checkbox? 
    && divelems[no].childNodes[i].checked ){                         // is checked?
      checks++;
        }
     i++;  
    }
 }
alert("no of checkboxes checked inside div are: "+checks);
}
</script>
</html>
```

**UPDATE2:**
pls check now

```
<html>
<script>
    function check(div){ //function can count checkboxes for divs elements that is passed in as argument

var checks= 0;
var divelem = document.getElementById(div);
var i=0;
while(i < divelem.childNodes.length){
if( divelem.childNodes[i].nodeType != 3         //not empty space
&& divelem.childNodes[i].getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox' //is checkbox? 
&& divelem.childNodes[i].checked ){                         // is checked?
  checks++;
    }
 i++;  
}

alert("no of checkboxes checked inside "+div+" are: "+checks);
}
</script>
<div id="div1" >
1.<input type="checkbox" value="check1" / ></br>
2.<input type="checkbox" value="check2" / ></br>
3.<input type="checkbox" value="check3" / ></br>
<input type="button" value="count check div1" onclick="check('div1')"> 
</div>
<div id="div2" >
4.<input type="checkbox" value="check4" / ></br>
5.<input type="checkbox" value="check5" / ></br>
</div>
<input type="button" value="count check div2 " onclick="check('div2')"> 
</html>
```

Comment: i will check this and make comment about this

Comment: it is not working brother i need to to count checked checkboxes on each div seperately